# Debugging intermittent failures with Apple IAP

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm working on an app with Swift 3, XCode 8.1, iOS 10.1.1. I'm testing my in-app purchases on my iPhone. About 30-40% of my purchase attempts are failing with SKError code 0: Cannot connect to iTunes Store. However, I can't figure out the pattern of the failures. IAPs that fail will frequently work if you just try again - same build, no changes, etc.

Things I've checked:

- I've verified that the product identifiers are correct, and have successfully purchased each IAP multiple times. There does not appear to be any problem getting the list of available products.
- I'm using a sandbox tester (gone through 6 of them at this point), having signed out of my regular account.
- I'm on my iPhone, not on Simulator.
- I've tried it under different network speeds using the Network Link Conditioner, with no change other than the success/failures happen faster or slower.
- My device has plenty of space, and the IAP isn't downloading anything anyway.
- Twitter isn't showing any complaints from other people about App Store issues.
- This same behavior is happening on two different devices, both iPhone 6.
- Each IAP is live and available.

Restoring purchases appears to work every time. I've seen some people on SO have success resetting their device when they can't get any IAP to work, but I'm hesitant to do that when my symptoms seem different.

Any suggestions on how to debug further?

Comment: When you use your test (sandbox) account, make sure  you don’t enter your test account information in the Store settings panel (on your phone). Doing so may invalidate your test account.

Comment: Huh, I knew I would get an error if I tried to enter my sandbox account in settings, but didn't know it could invalidate the account. Good to know, although unfortunately not the problem in this case - I've been signing out, deleting the app, and then re-entering when prompted for each sandbox user.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. With error 0, it's typically an invalid account or an invalid product id. You may want to try and create another fresh test account just to make sure... iAP is a pain to test....